# how to split big dataframe into smaller ones?

Tags: dataframe

I have a dataframe of 1556640 rows. I'd like to cut in into 1081 smaller dataframes like this :

x0=x.iloc[:1440]

x1=x.iloc[1441:2880]

x2=x.iloc[2881:4320]

...

x1081=x.iloc[1555201:]

Help would be welcome

Gilles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must to specify with ***more info***, but it's something like this:

```
#Declare
dataframe = 1556640
smallerDataFrame = 1081

vectors = []

#Loop
for x in range(smallerDataFrame):
     dataframe -= smallerDataFrame
     vectors.append(dataframe)

# Show
vectors
```

> Made with [Python™](https://www.python.org/)